# Return to the top of a for-loop midway through execution?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to go back to the top a for-loop if a certain condition in an inner if-statement is fulfilled. Is there any code that can do this?

Comment: you should debug your code.Also I think your question should be proper.It seems your question is not proper.

Comment: First could be pls provide some code? And then a for loop has and index value like for (int index=0; index < something; index) you can always set index inside your loop to what you want

Answer (score 6):

```
continue;
```

skips the rest of the loop and returns to the top.

Comment: Note that the *count* is incremented / decremented in case of a `for` loop i.e, the *third* argument to the loop will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to use `continue`?

```
String myTraingle = "";
for (int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
    myTraingle = "";
    for (int j=1;j<=9;j++) {
        myTraingle = myTraingle + " " + j;
        if (i==j) {
            System.out.println(myTraingle);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

### [*Demo*](https://ideone.com/MDhBw3)

Comment: The example works, but it would make more sense (to me) to avoid `continue` here and change the inner loop to `for (int j=1;j<=i;j++)` instead. ([Demo](https://ideone.com/imEoXU))

Comment: @Tom : I do understand... but I used that just to explain it more clearly what continue will do...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
continue;
```

And if you've got some nested loops use

```
continue <label>;
```

Examples are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

```
continue;
```

Skips the current iteration of a `for`, `while`, or `do-while` loop.

```
break;
```

Terminates the innermost `switch`, `for`, `while`, or `do-while` statement.

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
  if(i==0) continue; // skip
  if(i==10) break;   // terminate
  System.out.println(i);
} 
// prints: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (one per line)
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use **continue** statement. In every programming language including java, one can find certain condition in which loop has to iterate next iteration by discontinuing present iteration. continue is used only for that purpose. Just write continue; in inner if statement.

Answer (score 0):

When the if-statement is fulfilled, before using 'continue', overwrite count to '0'.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
  if(/* Some Condition */) 
  {
    i=0; // to go to top again.
    continue; 
  }
}
```